# Why have separate Long and Short Flush buttons on a toilet if they both do the same thing?

Tags: toilet

In my house, I have two buttons that I can use to flush my toilet. These buttons are labeled "Short Flush" and "Long Flush".

When pressing either of these and instantly letting go, the flush time is the same for either button. Even if I hold the button down until the sistern has completely emptied, the time it takes to re-fill it is the same no matter which button I press. Is there a logical reason for this? I can't figure out why separate buttons exist that do the same things - unless they actually both hit the same flush or similar (I'm not too confident in how these systems work)!

Comment: Do you have a manufacturer and/or model #?

Comment: Whoever installed it may have severely mal-adjusted it. Whether by accident/ignorance or by being one of those plumbers that does not like new-fangled water saving things and deliberately defeats them, hard to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those should have different effects. I suspect it's not working right. The expected result is that the short flush should cycle the water in the bowl, but not completely empty the tank. The long flush should empty the tank. If you have a manual or can find one, you might be able to adjust things.